# Status of WUXGA (1920x1200) laptops

Tags: laptop, display, lcd, aspect-ratio

I have and application that absolutely requires at least 1200 lines vertical. I cannot seem to find a laptop from my usual vendors with this resolution. Is the 16:10 aspect ratio dead? Why is 1080 considered better? Is it all about playing movies on your computer?

Comment: Voted to close as subjective/argumentative.  That said, yes, 16:10 is slowly dying, mostly because there's more demand for 16:9 "true HD" panels (yes, mostly for movies) and even if laptop manufacturers wanted to go all 16:10 they wouldn't be able to get the LCD panels because they aren't being made like they used to be.  (And I hate it too.)

Comment: Requires? Which one would this be?

Comment: @Shinrai, I was more asking about the status of the industry and not arguing that one is better than the other. Although I do think that the reduced vertical space is restricting on a range of typical productivity applications.

Comment: @Ignacio, it's a custom built monitoring application for scientic instruments. It has some visual displays that can't be scaled.

Comment: @Thomas - Less argumentative, more subjective.  Of course, everybody else is free to disagree with me. :)

Comment: is an external display not an option?

Comment: @acme64, we've been using external displays and desktops, but that limits portability.

Comment: It would appear that the only current laptop (that I've found) with a 1920x1200 resolution is the Apple MacBook Pro 17" but it carries with it the usual unnecessarily high Apple price tag. However, this proves that the panels are available - just that PC manufacturers are only too happy to saddle their creations with pitiful 1366x768 panels as standard (and call them 'HD'), and Full HD 1080 panels for their 'premium' models.